# NodeJs VS code not showing members of object

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am new to **NodeJS** and **JavaScript**.

Visual studio does not seem to show class members when I press dot after the object instance. Is there any setting I am missing or what may be wrong. I am on ubuntu 22.04 and have installed NodeJS. The screen shot is below. Any help would be appreciated

[image: Text]